# GCloud Vision API Code 7 We're not allowed to access the URL on your behalf. Please download the content and pass it in

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

When i call the google vision api for analyzing text on a picture, the direct url to the picture from another cloud (onedrive) can not be accessed. the response is:

`ERROR: (gcloud.ml.vision.detect-text) Code: [7] Message: [We're not allowed to access the URL on your behalf. Please download the content and pass it in.]`

Currently i use the gcloud cli for windows:

`gcloud ml vision detect-text https://public.am.files.1drv.com/exampleurl` (<--- there is an forever long id instead of "exampleurl"

Does somebody know a solution for this except from downloading the image manually?

Comment: You have at least 3 options. Make the OneDrive URL public so that any client (including `gcloud`) can access it. Determine whether OneDrive provides a way to generate a Signed URL for the image so that only you know the URL and can provide it to `gcloud` to more securely access the URL. Write code using Google's (and OneDrive?) SDKs that allow you to authenticate the OneDrive client request, retrieve the object and pass it to Google's Vision service.

Comment: Another option is to use a local proxy for OneDrive (e.g. one of Microsoft's OneDrive apps). You could then access the local copy of the OneDrive file that needs no further authentication rather than go to the OneDrive service for the file which does.

Comment: Hi OP, does any of @DazWilkin 's suggestions work for you? Easiest option out of his 3 suggestions would be the first one that makes the OneDrive URL public (if your pictures can be publicly accessible).

Comment: @DazWilkin Thanks for ideas! I have unfortunately the problem that the url above is already without any restrictions and the idea with the sharing of a file I have also tried, but comes the same error code. 
how to make it possible that the google sdk gets the authorization to onedrive? i don't know. i don't think that would work so easily either.
the local proxy could be an option, but since the code acts as a daemon on the server side, this option is probably out as well.

Comment: I don't understand "the url is already without any restrictions". If the URL is public, then `gcloud` will be able to access it.

Comment: Microsoft provides SDKs for OneDrive (e.g. [OneDrive file storage API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/onedrive-concept-overview)). Using that you would be able to retrieve files from OneDrive (you'll need to provide whatever credentials are required) and then you could use one of Google's [Vision client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/libraries) to annotate the files.

Comment: to your first comment @DazWilkin : the URL is definitely public (i tried it on completely different devices with tor browser.) but gcloud still doesn't recognize it unfortunately.
to your second comment: But then I would download the file again and spend traffic but that's what I want to avoid.

Comment: Last comment. If you can `curl https://public.am.files.1drv.com/exampleurl --output /dev/null --write-out '%{response_code}'` with a 200 then the issue is with `gcloud`. Try `gcloud ml vision detect-text https://public.am.files.1drv.com/exampleurl --log-http --verbosity=debug`, identity the issue and file it with Google's [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com).

Comment: There would be no need to "download the file again" if you use an SDK. The code would pass the file reference from OneDrive to the Cloud SDK.

Comment: Ok so there is an 200 with the url, gcloud cli is probably broken. I will look if i find another possibility.